# How to import react in background.js of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, google-chrome-extension, react-dom

I want to use reactDOM for injecting content to page. So, I want to

```
import React from 'react';
...
import App from './src/js/App';

const root=createRoot(document.getElementById('title'));
root.render(
   <App/>
);
```

included into my background.js but I get the following
error: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Import that is causing the error:

import React from 'react'

I've done some research and tried adding  type: "module" but that does not work.

What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many research,

I did npm run eject

here is the working react setup

https://github.com/rba1aji/chrome-extension-template-react

Answer (score 0):

Facing pretty similar issues atm, digging SO for a while.

Try to play around with

```
import React from './react.js'; // path and file extension here
```

or

```
import * as React from './react.js'; // another import option
```

Also, ensure you have manifest v3 in order `type: "module"` to work.